# Unable to launch ECS instance with SSM parameters as secrets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm currently trying to launch a website as an ECS Service and am having trouble getting the ECS Task to properly launch. It keeps erroring out with the following message:

```
ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve secrets from ssm: service call has been retried 5 time(s): RequestCanceled: request context canceled caused by: context deadline exceeded. Please check your task network configuration.
```

I have the following for my VPC definitions, which includes a NAT Gateway that the Task *should* be using for communicating outside the private subnets:

```
  MyVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: true
  MyDefaultRouteTable:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
  MyRouteTableA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
  MyRouteTableB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
  MyPublicSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: "us-east-2a"
      CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/24"
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
  MyPublicSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: "us-east-2b"
      CidrBlock: "10.0.2.0/24"
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
  MyPrivateSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: "us-east-2a"
      CidrBlock: "10.0.1.0/24"
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
  MyPrivateSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: "us-east-2b"
      CidrBlock: "10.0.3.0/24"
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
  MyInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Env
          Value: production
  MyInternetGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref MyInternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
  MyNatGatewayEIPA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  MyNatGatewayA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt MyNatGatewayEIPA.AllocationId
      ConnectivityType: public
      SubnetId: !Ref MyPrivateSubnetA
  MyNatGatewayRouteA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
      NatGatewayId: !Ref MyNatGatewayA
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTableA
  MyNatGatewayEIPB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  MyNatGatewayB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt MyNatGatewayEIPB.AllocationId
      ConnectivityType: public
      SubnetId: !Ref MyPrivateSubnetB
  MyNatGatewayRouteB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
      NatGatewayId: !Ref MyNatGatewayB
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTableB
  MyRouteTableAssociationA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTableA
      SubnetId: !Ref MyPrivateSubnetA
  MyRouteTableAssociationB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTableB
      SubnetId: !Ref MyPrivateSubnetB
```

My ECS configuration is as such:

```
MyExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchFullAccess
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "Logs"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:Create
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutDestination
                Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        - PolicyName: "GetSecrets"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ssm:GetParameters
                  - kms:Decrypt
                  - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/*"
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:*"
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:kms:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:key/*"
  MyECSLogsGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: "/ecs/website"
      RetentionInDays: 90
  MyECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: website
      Tags:
        - Key: Env
          Value: production
  MyECSTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Command:
            - /app/docker-entry.sh
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-region: !Sub "${AWS::Region}"
              awslogs-group: !Ref MyECSLogsGroup
              awslogs-stream-prefix: qjr
          Environment:
            - Name: REDIS_HOST
              Value: !Ref RedisHost
            - Name: REDIS_PORT
              Value: !Ref RedisPort
          Essential: true
          Image: !Sub "${RepositoryUri}:latest"
          Memory: !!int 1024
          Name: website
          Cpu: !!int 512
          PortMappings:
            - AppProtocol: http
              ContainerPort: !!int 4200
              HostPort: !!int 4200
              Protocol: tcp
          Secrets:
            - Name: DATABASE_URL
              ValueFrom: !Ref DatabaseUrlArn
            - Name: GH_TOKEN
              ValueFrom: !Ref GHTokenArn
            - Name: JWT_SECRET
              ValueFrom: !Ref JWTSecretArn
            - Name: SECRET_KEY
              ValueFrom: !Ref SecretKeyArn
            - Name: YUBIKEY_CLIENT_ID
              ValueFrom: !Ref YubikeyClientIdArn
            - Name: YUBIKEY_CLIENT_SECRET
              ValueFrom: !Ref YubikeyClientSecretArn
          User: node:node
      Cpu: !!int 512
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt MyExecutionRole.Arn
      Memory: !!int 1024
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      RuntimePlatform:
        CpuArchitecture: X86_64
        OperatingSystemFamily: LINUX
      TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt MyTaskRole.Arn
  MyECSService:
    DependsOn:
      - MyECSTaskDefinition
      - MyTargetGroup
      - MyLoadBalancer
      - MyLoadBalancerListener
      - MyECSIngressSecurityGroup
      - MyECSEgressSecurityGroup
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref MyECSCluster
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: !!int 100
        MinimumHealthyPercent: !!int 0
      DeploymentController:
        Type: ECS
      DesiredCount: !!int 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: website
          ContainerPort: !!int 4200
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - !GetAtt MyECSEgressSecurityGroup.GroupId
            - !GetAtt MyECSIngressSecurityGroup.GroupId
          Subnets: !Ref PrivateSubnets
      PlatformVersion: LATEST
      SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
      ServiceName: website
      TaskDefinition: !Ref MyECSTaskDefinition
  MyECSIngressSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      GroupDescription: Inbound Traffic
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !!int 4200
          ToPort: !!int 4200
  MyECSEgressSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      GroupDescription: Outbound traffic
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: -1
```

I don't see, at least from my end, why the ECS Task can't connect to the internet to retrieve the secrets information from AWS.